# which version should i use for ruby 1.8.7 in Cent os 5.5 x64

Tags: ruby

ruby 1.8.7 has p302 and p330 versions, i want to install ruby in centos x64 and rails of 2.3.5, but i am not sure which version should i use ?

Could someone give me some recommendations for me? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, you should use the latest version unless you have very specific reasons not to.

You should also update Rails to 2.3.12 if possible to address some [security issues](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/6/8/ann-rails-2-3-12-has-been-released) in earlier releases.

Comment: is p330 is more stable than p302? is there something to note for rails 2.3.5? could you point to me?

Comment: If you're using 1.8.7, you should use the highest patch release for that version. I don't know if there's anything specifically wrong with 2.3.5, but the XSS patch in .12 is an example of the kinds of exposure you have with older versions.